# OOPs paradigm in Python

Tags: java, c++, python, oop

Here is something I've been having a doubt about. Consider the following snippet.

```
class A(object):
    def check(self):
        super(A, self).check()
        print "inside a"

class B(object):
    def check(self):
        print "inside b"

class C(A, B):
    pass

c = C()
c.setup()
```

Now this gives the output,

```
inside b
inside a
```

Passing this through pdb i see that on reaching A.setup(), B.setup() is being called. However, the call from A is to the check method of its superclass; as it does not exist the call moves from that point to B.check().

1. Could someone explain or point me to a document which explains how this works internally? I could'nt find any.
2. Could someone show me a similar implementation in C++/Java? I think comparing it with other languages would help me understand the problem at hand better.

Many thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, Guido has a blog in which he tells us a little bit of python's history. In a recent article he talks about the Method Resolution Order: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Answer (score 9):

The algorithm is explained in [this excellent article](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html).

In short,

`super(A,self)` looks in `self.__class__.__mro__` for the next class *after* `A`.

In your case, `self` is `c`, so `self.__class__` is `C`.
`C.__mro__` is `[C,A,B,object]`. So the next class in the MRO after `A` happens to be `B`.

So `super(A,self)` returns a `super` object which behaves like `B` as far as attribute lookup is concerned.

`super(A, self).check()` thus calls `B.check()`.

[The C3 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) Python uses to generate the MRO (Method Resolution Order) is also described in a little more detail in [this essay](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) by Michele Simionato.

Comment: +1 for delaying my fourth of July activities with an "oh crap I can't stop reading this" article.

Comment: Oh yes, my family loves it when I regale them the full story of Python attribute lookup while we watch the big screensaver in the sky.